# Camera in Android app doesn't take picture when preview size is set to a particular value obtained frome supported preview size

Tags: android, camera

I am facing this bizzare issue in my app where the camera doesn't capture the picture when I set the parameters.setPreviewSize(width,height) to a particular value obtained from supported preview sizes(Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()). When I try with some other sizes (obtained from supported preview size), camera takes the picture.

First I am opening the camera & setting the camera parameters in surfaceChanged method. I am aiming to set the preview size of the camera depending upon the width & height of the device screen. I am looking for the largest size supported whose width is less than or equal to the width of the screen device.

On Nexus 4 I get the value as 768 * 432. Here is the list of all the sizes when I loop thru getSupportedPreviewSizes();

Width  Height
1280 * 720
800 * 480
768 * 432
720 * 480
640 * 480
576 * 432
480 * 320
384 * 288
352 * 288
320 * 240
240 * 160
176 * 144

I set the preview size as 768 * 432 as below :-
parameters.setPreviewSize(768, 432);

and then set some other parameters and finally camera.setParameters(parameters); and camera.startPreview().

When I click capture button autofocus callback executes :-

```
 Camera.AutoFocusCallback mAutoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
    };
```

but then camera.takePicture doesn't call the rest of the callbacks, where the picture is actually taken.

Same code works if I set the preview size as 800 * 480 or 720 * 480 or any other from the list above.

As of now this issue is reported only on Nexus 4. The camera is running great on many other devices.

Is there a way I can be sure that the preview size that I select on a particular device will always work on that device ?.

Can someone please throw some light on this.

Thanks a lot in advance.
harsh86

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the preview before taking the picture.

Answer (score 0):

The preview size is hardware-related. It's not guaranteed the preview size you obtained from one device can work on other device. You have to check supported preview size on every device. In addition, you can never 100% trust all of the obtained preview size. Some of them may not work due to the hardware. I've got the experience when I wanna set some preview size on Samsung's device, not all preview size could work. So sometimes, you have to try different preview size.